# Angle for tracking compass.

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I am currently writing a tracking app that is able to get your currently facing angle and the angle to a destination and point an arrow in the direction you need to travel. (As the crow flies)

I am having trouble taking these 2 angles and making them work together so that the arrow points in the correct direction.

My knowledge of Mathematics is extremely limited so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the form of the input and the form of the output.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by form but the input is the facing degrees (0-360) and the same for the destination.

Comment: I also need the output to be in degrees

Comment: Well then sounds like the answer to your question is $(360+\text{dest}-\text{face})\bmod{360}$.

Comment: Ok i understand that except mod. what is mod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s$ denote the source heading.

Let $d$ denote the destination heading.

Then the desired heading is simply $(360+d-s)\bmod{360}$.

---

If you wish to avoid the use of "$\bmod$", then you can write it as:

$H(d,s)=360+d-s-360\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{360+d-s}{360}\right\rfloor$

---

If you wish to avoid the use of "$\left\lfloor\dots\right\rfloor$", then you can write it as:

$H(d,s)=\cases
 {
  d \geq s &$d-s$\\
  d   <  s &$360+d-s$\\
 }
$

---

If you wish to avoid the use of "$\cases{\dots\\\dots\\}$", then you can write it as:

$H(d,s)=\sqrt[2]{(d-s)^2}$

Comment: @Mattigins: Please note my correction to the $3$rd option (out of $4$ options).

Comment: Got it working with the mod. Thanks